# How to index a document which has geojson as a field in Solr?

Tags: solr, geospatial, geojson, solrcloud

When I try to index a document which has a location type field there is no result for it. I'm trying to index documents then I hope I will be able to search spatially.

I'm following [link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/spatial-search.html) and I also use SolrCloud version 7.5 but I can not search spatially with using geojson attributes properly.

my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
...
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="geo_location" type="location" stored="true"/>
<field name="otherProperty" type="string" stored="true"/>
```

The document contains a geojson and any property field

When I try to index this document using rest api

```
{
    "id":"12345",
    "location_try": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                125.6,
                10.1
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "Dinagat Islands"
        }
    },
    "otherProperty":"something"
}
```

http://localhost:8983/solr/geoCollection/update/json/docs?commitWithin=1000&overwrite=true&wt=json&format=geojson

After the indexing operation is complete then the managed-schame is changed to

```
...
<field name="location_try" type="location" stored="true"/>
<field name="location_try.geometry.coordinates" type="pdoubles"/>
<field name="location_try.geometry.type" type="text_general"/>
<field name="location_try.properties.name" type="text_general"/>
<field name="location_try.type" type="text_general"/>
```

I can see my document in collection but i can't get response from query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/geoCollection/select?&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt sfield=location_try}&pt=10.11,11.11&d=1
```

How can I index geojson properly and search with spatial fields in solr? For example I want to get documents within bounding box or polygons?

Comment: The endpoint in the example from the manual above is `http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update?format=geojson`, without `json/docs`. Also start by setting the field as `stored="true"` to see the content indexed for the field. Are you committing after submitting the document? How are you querying for the document afterwards?

Comment: You're right I forgot the commit, fixed and updated to question, shortly I want to query with bounding boxes or polygons to get documents which are at given area?